# Не могу отправить не пустую строку с помощью Telegram API

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

У меня есть Telegram Bot шифратор. Он использует XOR шифрование. Когда я передаю боту
сообщение для шифровки: 'a'
ключ для шифровки: 'e'
у меня получается символ ♦, но я не могу отослать этот символ пользователю когда он находится в переменной. Однако, когда я вручную вставляю этот символ в качестве текста для отправки - он отправляется успешно.

```
 uint a = 'a';
 uint e = 'e';
 char letter = (char)(a ^ e);
 string result = string.Empty;
 result += letter;
 Console.WriteLine(result.Length + result);
 await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, result);
```

Вывод в консоль:

1♦

Telegram API Error:
[400]
Bad Request: message must be non-empty

Свойство result'a явно говорит, что мой текст для отправки не пустой. Почему Telegram API считает, что я передаю ему пустую строку и как мне это исправить?

Upd.

Я проверил uint-code символов, на первый взгляд одинаковых, но символ который получается после шифрации "a" ^ "e" имеет код 9840, но скопированный в буфер он имеет код 4.

Comment: Насколько я вижу Вы получаете непечатный символ который вероятно и не может считаться строкой, консоль вместо него выводит ромбик (это другой символ) при отсылке которого проблем не возникает.